# Seeding data in custom Db Initializer won't work / EF, Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to seed some data using custom database initializers, but can't get it to work. I tried adding some configurations to appConfig file but that didn't work either.

It is a WPF application and I don't want to reference my EntityLibrary. I want to seed data using context's constructor. What's wrong with it?

Edit: The problem is no data gets populated. When debugging I see the context's constructor SetInitiazlier function is called but overridden Seed method never gets called, in fact debugger never enters the Seed method.

At the same time XAML parser gives an error complaining about the TContext type paramter of 
DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges. I can't give the exact error since I don't have the code at home.

This is my custom initializer:

```
public class DbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DemirbaşContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(DemirbaşContext context)
        {
            Kullanıcı kullanıcı = new Kullanıcı
            {
                Ad = "Mert",
                Soyad = "Mert",
                KullanıcıAdı = "admin",
                Şifre = "password",
                Email = "mert@mert.com"
            };

            context.Kullanıcılar.Add(kullanıcı);
            context.SaveChanges();

            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

This is my context constructor:

```
public DemirbaşContext():base("Demirbaş")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DemirbaşContext>(new DbInitializer());
    }
```

EDIT 1: Here is my current code, but still it does not seed the data. Can you see what's wrong?

Initializer:

```
public class DbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DemirbaşContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(DemirbaşContext context)
    {
        Kullanıcı kullanıcı = new Kullanıcı
        {
            Ad = "Mert",
            Soyad = "Mert",
            KullanıcıAdı = "admin",
            Şifre = "password",
            Email = "mert@mert.com"
        };

        context.Kullanıcılar.Add(kullanıcı);
        context.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

Application Startup:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            // Seed data, remove after getting seeding in custom db initiazlier to work
            DemirbaşContext context = new DemirbaşContext();
            DbInitializer initializer = new DbInitializer();
            Database.SetInitializer<DemirbaşContext>(initializer);
            context.Database.Initialize(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *I am trying to seed some data using custom database initializers, but can't get it to work. I tried adding some configurations to appConfig file but that didn't work either.* Is not description of the problem. Every time I see *it doesn't work* without explaining what is really happening (exception, no database, no data, etc.) I'm considering downvoting and voting to close the question as "Not a real question". Asking a good descriptive question is a necessary step to get an answer.

Comment: You are right. I edited the question. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Did you actually ever used EF in your application? Loading something from database or storing something to database?

Comment: Yes it matters because the first usage of the context for persisting or loading data will trigger the initializer - not the constructor itself.

Comment: I am trying to insert an admin account to the table in the initializer. After that when the application runs, the user enters some username and password and tries to login but there is no account in the database. Should I do a trivial insert/delete operation to get the initializer run before trying to access the admin account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your initialization code to your application startup. It doesn't belong to context's constructor and force initialization manually:

```
Database.SetInitializer<DemirbaşContext>(new DbInitializer());
context.Database.Initialize(false);
```

Comment: There is no Initialize method in Database class in EF 4.3.1, I think it comes with 5.0 Beta. What is the option for 4.3.1?

Comment: I'm sorry. It is instance method - I modified the answer.